# jQuery does not work on XHTML page

Tags: jquery, xhtml

This is the code to my XHTML page. jQuery is in the `/js/` folder in my application. All other pages' validation is done with jQuery using the same file, but I cannot run a simple jQuery code on this test page that I've created. This is the code of the page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
            });

        </script>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <p>Not loaded yet.</p>
        <input id="pedram" type="text" onclick="alert('hi');"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I have also tried to use `CDATA` tag. I have also moved the script to the head of the document.

The only thing that works correctly is the `alert()` that I've put inside the `onclick` event. Nothing else works.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 8):

change

```
<script src="js/jquery.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
        });
</script>
```

To

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
        });
</script>
```

You don't need to specify jQuery source twice.. nor do you need to when you are using js inside the tags

Comment: check your console.. is your jQuery getting loaded?  Is it saying $ is not a function?

Comment: so if the alert works, i can assume jquery library is loaded right? but why other stuff does not work?

Comment: nope.. alert will work regardless if jQuery loaded or not.. alert() is a javascript method

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`  <-- remove yours and use that to see if it works

Comment: that's the problem. my console does not show jquery errors. is there a way i can do this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17611/discussion-between-wirey-and-pedram)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the context path of my application (java) and add to my jquery library address.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your use of `<h:body>` in conjunction with jQuery 1.x.

Using either jQuery 2.x or `<body>` will solve your problem.

jQuery 1.x is likely using `document.body` somewhere, which fails because `document.body` is null when using `<h:body>`.

---

*If you don't mind my asking, why are you using the h namespace (http://java.sun.com/jsf/html)?*